# Compute the determinant $4\times 4$

Tags: linear-algebra, determinant

Compute the determinant:
$$
       A= \begin{vmatrix}
        1 & 1 & a+1 & b+1 \\
         1 & 0 & a & b \\
         2 & b & a & b \\
        2 & a & a & b \\
        \end{vmatrix}
$$

I got (in the end): $\det A = (-a-b)(b+a) = -ab -a^2 -b^2 -ba $.

Comment: I don't think your answer can be right.  If $a=1$ and $b=1$, the last two rows are equal and so the determinant is 0, but your computation would give $-4$.

Comment: I can upload a picture how I computed it if you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can preform some row operations, they preserve the determinant (but no multiplying a row and $-1$ for every transopsition). This gives me

$$-\begin{vmatrix}
1&0&a&b\\
0&1&1&1\\
0&0&-(a+b)&-2b\\
0&0&-2a&-(a+b)\\
\end{vmatrix}$$

So determinant is $-[(a+b)^2-4ab]$

Comment: Any chance you can write for me what are the row operations to get the determinant? I'd very much appreciate it.

Comment: First use the second row to get zeros in the first column, (except the second row). Then use first row to get zeros in second column, now switch first and second row. Now you can check to see if I made a mistake !

Comment: You're totally right. Good computation! Thx!

Comment: Or simplified a little further, $-(a-b)^2$.

Comment: In the end its so simple...